# Solicitation for suggestions on writing a purely hobbyist rendering engine

Tags: graphics, high-level, rendering-engine

I've created something of a simplistic renderer on my own using OpenGL ES 2.0.  Essentially, it's just a class for rendering quads according to a given sprite texture.  To elaborate, it's really just a single object that accepts objects that represent quads.  Each quad object maintains a a world transform and object transform matrix and furnishes methods for transforming them over a given number of frames and also specifies texture offsets into the sprite.  This quad class also maintains a list of transform operations to execute on its matrices.  The renderer class then reads all of these properties from the quad and sets up a VBO to draw all quads in the render list.

For example:

```
Quad q1 = new Quad();
Quad q2 = new Quad();

q1->translate(vector3( .1, .3, 0), 30); // Move the quad to the right and up for 30 frames.
q2->translate(vector3(-.1, -.3, 0), 30); // Move the quad down and to the left for 30 frames.

Renderer renderer;
renderer.addQuads({q1, q2});
It's more complex than this, but you get the simple idea.
```

From the implementation perspective, on each frame, it transforms the base vertices of each object according to instruction, loads them all into a VBO including info on alpha value, and passes to a shader program to draw all quad at once.

This obviously isn't what I would call a rendering engine, but performs a similar task, just for rendering 2D quads instead of 3D geometry.  I'm just curious as to whether I'm on the right track for developing a makeshift rendering engine.  I agree that in most cases it's great to use an established rendering engine to get started in understanding them, but from my point of view, I like to have something of an understanding of how things are implemented, as opposed to learning something prebuilt and then learning how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this approach is that adding new geometry, textures or animations requires writing code.  It should be possible to create content for a game engine using established tools, like 3DS, Maya or Blender, which are completely interactive.  This requires reading and parsing some standard file format like Collada.  I don't want to squash your desire to learn by implementing code yourself, but you really should take a look at the PowerVR SDK, which provides a lot of the important parts for building game engines.  The source code is provided and it's free.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  At this point, I'm more interested in how things work on a fundamental level which is why I want to do something on my own.  My concern is not to create a game so much as it is to create a simplistic model rendering engine, related to something one would do in school.  I've started writing a simple asset loader that uses Assimp to load OBJ models and want to create a simple renderer and move the models with keyboard and mouse.